# Existence of limit of the following:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f:\left( {0,\infty } \right) \to \left( {0,\infty } \right)$ be differentiable function. Show that the following exists and can't be 0:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{a \to 0} {\left( {\frac{{f\left( {x + ax} \right)}}{{f\left( x \right)}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{a}}}$$

My intuition tells me that it's the form of $e$ to the power of something but I cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\ln$ of the expression:
$$
\ln {\left( {\frac{{f\left( {x + ax} \right)}}{{f\left( x \right)}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{a}}}=\frac{\ln (f(x+ax))-\ln (f(x))}{a}=\frac{\ln (f(x+ax))-\ln (f(x))}{ax}\, x.
$$
Now recognize that the fraction looks like in the definition of the derivative
$$
\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\to F'(x),\qquad h\to 0.
$$
Hence the limit is
$$
(\ln f(x))'\cdot x=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}.
$$
Back to the original limit:
$$
\exp\left(\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\right).
$$

Comment: I thought $f\left( {x + ax} \right)$ is actually a composition of $f(x)$ and $g(x)=x+ax$. Can you really do that when $h$ is a function of $x$?

Comment: @singalong2019 $h$ is a function of $x$, but it does not matter, because the calculation is done for a *fixed* $x$. Basically you can thing that $x$ is a number (constant). The only that matters here is $a$, and $a\to 0$. So $h=ax\to 0$, and everything is alright. Compare with $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F(2+2t)-F(2)}{t}=[h=2t]=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(2+h)-F(2)}{h}\cdot 2.$$

Comment: okay this makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would write $(\ln f)'(x)$ instead of $(\ln f(x))'.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is differentiable we have that as $h\to 0$

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+hf'(x_0)+o(h)$$

and then

$$\left( {\frac{{f\left( {x + ax} \right)}}{{f\left( x \right)}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{a}}=\left( {\frac{{f(x)+axf'(x)+o(a) }}{{f\left( x \right)}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{a}}=$$

$$=\left( 1+{\frac{axf'(x) }{{f\left( x \right)}}+o(a)} \right)^{\frac{1}{a}}=e^{\frac1a\log\left( 1+{\frac{axf'(x) }{{f\left( x \right)}}+o(a)} \right)}=e^{\frac{xf'(x)}{f( x )}+o(1)}\to e^{\frac{xf'(x)}{f( x )}}>0$$

Comment: So I assume you can apply the linear approximation when $h$ is a function of x too? If so why is it $o\left( a \right)$ instead of $o\left( {ax} \right)$?

Comment: @singalong2019 It is a first order expansion and we have $o(ax)=o(a)$.

Comment: I am not sure if I get that but ok and also is it that $o\left( a \right) = \frac{{o\left( a \right)}}{{f\left( x \right)}}$?

Comment: @singalong2019 Yes since $f(x)$ is just a number, we are considering $a\to 0$.

Comment: @singalong2019 Recall the definition for little o notation: $$o(ax)=\omega(ax)\cdot ax= x\omega(ax)\cdot a=\omega_1(ax)\cdot a=o(a)$$